# Texlive 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04: Font WebOMintsGD not found

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu

I upgraded to `Texlive 2014` on `Unbutu 14.04` and after this I'm getting this error (for some files):

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not
>   found

I would highly appreciate if someone help me to figure out this problem. Thanks

**Edited**

I asked the question which is liked as duplicated. At `Texlive 2014` on `Unbutu 14.04`, I'm not able to fix the problem

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not
>   found

even after install the required fonts. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

I found this [link about the same problem](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/sK0ydyiOYWwpKf22YGEx) but still struggling.

I used `getnonfreefonts-l` to check the installed fonts and this command shows `Webomints` font in this list. Even then I'm getting the same error (Might be in different directory, looked [this link](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/sK0ydyiOYWwpKf22YGEx) for the same problem where fonts were in different directory). I'm not very expert and struggling with it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The WebOMints font is not distributed with TeX Live for licensing issues. You can install it with `getnonfreefonts-sys`, see https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Comment: @egreg: Please see my edits.

Comment: Sorry, but just saying "I'm not able to fix the problem” is not sufficient to get more help than “use `getnonfreefonts`”.

Comment: @egreg: I used `getnonfreefonts-l` to check the installed fonts and this command shows `Webomints` font in this list. Even then I'm getting the same error (Might be in different directory). I'm not very expert and struggling with it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I told you to use `getnonfreefonts-sys`

Comment: Please, specify what TeX distribution you're using: the Debian one or the “vanilla” TUG?

Comment: Thanks @egreg for helping me. The output of `getnonfreefonts-sys` shows   `Directories:   temporary: '/tmp/getfont-<PID>' install:   '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'` and the output of `getnonfreefonts` shows `Directories: temporary: '/tmp/getfont-<PID>'  install:   '/home/yaseen/texmf'`.`

Comment: In order to use `getnonfreefonts-sys` you need to prefix it with `sudo`.

Comment: Yes I used `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys` and its output (not full) is `Directories: temporary: '/tmp/getfont-<PID>'     install:   '/usr/local/share/texmf'`.

Comment: Seems OK to me. You should ensure you remove the `pdftex.map` files that usage of `getnonfreefonts` created. Do `kpsewhich pdftex.map` and, if the output points to a file in your space, remove that file.

Comment: But both `Texmaker` and `RStudio` throws the error:  `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not found `. My experience of switching from Windows to Ubuntu is very painful after getting this error. Not able to compile many files.

Comment: Getting the same error even after removing `pdftex.map` files. Please @egreg scan the [provided link](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/sK0ydyiOYWwpKf22YGEx) about the same problem. Please consider to open this question.