# Quattrocento in Ubuntu 14.04 (TeXLive 2014)

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu, linux

Although I went over here: 
[Texlive 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04: Font WebOMintsGD not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213874/texlive-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04-font-webomintsgd-not-found)

and here:

[Installing missing fonts in Texlive on Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212600/installing-missing-fonts-in-texlive-on-ubuntu)

I'm unable to use `quattrocento` in my Ubuntu 14.04 distro.  Any help would be appreciated.

Oh, and just in case you were wondering... yes, I'm loading the package with `\usepackage{quattrocento}`.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu's packages, you need to figure out which package includes `quattrocento`. Unlike WebOMints, `quattrocento` is part of TeX Live proper so you don't need an extra script to install it - just the relevant bit of TeX Live. If you installed TeX Live from upstream, you should already have it assuming you installed the 'full' scheme.

Comment: @cfr how can I check that? I'm not good with this Linux thing.  More importantly, why it is not getting called when I use the `\usepackage` if it's supposed to be installed by default?

Comment: If you install upstream's version, it is installed by default. If you use Ubuntu's packages, it is in the package Ubuntu decided to put it in. I can't tell you which one as I don't use Ubuntu. Probably you can search packages by keyword or something like that to find it?

Comment: This is one reason I never use my distro's TeX Live packages... I always install from upstream. That said, for one of the distros I use, it is `texlive-fontsextra`. Possibly in something somewhat similar on Ubuntu.

Comment: @cfr can I update them? perhaps some `sudo apt-get update something` ?

Comment: You need to install the right package. Which package that is depends on how Ubuntu split up TeX Live. Every distro does this a bit differently, makes different decisions about how to divide TeX Live up. I think doing this is a bad idea in the first place, which is why I don't recommend using it. But if you want to stick to Ubuntu's packages, that's just the way it is :(.

Comment: I just realized the Ubuntu Software Center says: "TeXLive: a decent selection of TeX Live packages"

Comment: You might consider [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). You will also get more current versions of packages this way - sometimes by years.

Comment: @cfr Seems interesting, I'll give it a try. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ubuntu lets you load packages through the Synaptic Package Manager. Open it up, search using the 2 terms latex and font and it is, as cfr indicates, in `texlive-fonts-extra`. Click on the box to the left of the package and then press "Apply".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a search on my system (Kubuntu 14.04):

```
   sudo apt-cache search quattrocento
   fonts-quattrocento - classic, elegant, sober and strong Roman typeface
   texlive-fonts-extra - TeX Live: Additional fonts
```

Please install the package "texlive-fonts-extra" and you should be able to use this font.